# How to npm update packages efficiently

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'd like to update the packages of my [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) Angular 4 project. I'm running `npm 5` and `node 8.1` Here is the result of `npm outdated`

```
C:\project>npm outdated
Package                                 Current        Wanted        Latest
@angular/animations                       4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/common                           4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/compiler                         4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli                     4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/core                             4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/forms                            4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/http                             4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/language-service                 4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/material                  2.0.0-beta.7  2.0.0-beta.8  2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser                 4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic         4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@angular/router                           4.2.5         4.2.6         4.2.6
@types/gulp                               4.0.2         4.0.4         4.0.4
@types/node                              6.0.79        6.0.79         8.0.9
chart.js                                  2.4.0         2.6.0         2.6.0
codelyzer                                 3.0.1         3.0.1         3.1.2
crypto-js                                 3.1.7         3.1.8       3.1.9-1
karma-chrome-launcher                     2.1.1         2.1.1         2.2.0
rxjs                                      5.4.1         5.4.2         5.4.2
ts-node                                   3.0.6         3.0.6         3.2.0
tslint                                    5.3.2         5.3.2         5.5.0
typescript                                2.3.4         2.3.4         2.4.1
```

I want to update all the `@angular/` packages, but leave the other ones (eg: chart.js, crypto-js) alone. Is there an efficient way to do this or do I need to manually enter `npm update <package-name>` for each package?

Comment: `yarn upgrade-interactive` :) [Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade-interactive/)

Comment: https://github.com/dylang/npm-check

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thank you. These require that I add new tools. Was hoping to do this with vanilla NPM

Comment: I know. That's why I have posted it as a comment. Haven't heard there is something like that built in npm. You could also take you dependencies and do something like `Object.keys({/*dependencies*/}).filter(key => key.startsWith('@angular/')).join(' ')` to filter all angular related deps. Then copy-paste to cli `npm up ...`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko nifty! where would I paste something like that? And how would I run it?

Comment: Node repl would suffice. `node -e "console.log(Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies).filter(...).join(' '))" `